# Two Prometheus with same data repository

Tags: prometheus

Can two Prometheus server write to same remote data storage endpoint without any duplicate data created ?
I am trying to build setup with 2 Prometheus server for high availability.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is out of scope of the Prometheus project. Look into something like Thanos or Cortex. Both of these solutions provide scalability and high availability. Something like VictoriaMetrics may also be an option if your environment isn't Kubernetes based and you prefer something "simpler" at least regarding the setup.

Comment: VictoriaMetrics works perfectly in cloud and Kubernetes - see [Helm charts](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/helm-charts) and [Kubernetes operator](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/operator/).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write data from multiple identically configured Prometheus instances (aka HA pair) to the same [remote storage](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage) such as VictoriaMetrics. In this case data de-duplication must be enabled on VictoriaMetrics side - see [these docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#deduplication) for details.